# willSet/didSet called on a container's stored property x when setting a property of x

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I observed that behaviour that I don't quite understand. When executing this code in a playground:

```
protocol Testp {
    var notes: String { get set }
}

class Testc: Testp {
    var notes: String = "x"
}

class TestContainer {
    var test: Testp = Testc() {
        willSet {
            print("willSet")
        }
        didSet {
            print("didSet")
        }
    }
}

var testContainer = TestContainer()
print(testContainer.test.notes) // prints "x"

// this triggers a willSet+didSet call on TestContainer's
// stored property, even though "test" is not changed in testContainer
testContainer.test.notes = "y"

print(testContainer.test.notes) // prints "y"
```

As commented above, the `willSet` and `didSet` blocks are called even though the property itself is not being set.

On the other hand, if I change the protocol to be of type class as follow

```
protocol Testp: class {
    var notes: String { get set }
}
```

then the result is as I would expect it to be (i.e. no call to `willSet/didSet`).

What is the reason for this behaviour?

I run this on XCode 7.3.

Update: Still in XCode 9.2 / Swift 4

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Seeing the same issue.

Comment: I am selfishly happy to finally see someone else ending up in a context where this caused problems ;) Sorry, but no, I never resolved this any other way than doing things differently.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Testp` could easily be either `class` or a `struct`. If it is a `struct` then assign `testContainer.test.notes = "y"` will create a totally new instance of `Testp` implementer. On the other hand, by making `protocol Testp: class` you explicitely tell that assignment to `notes` won't change the `test`.

Consider a function

```
func doSomething(_ container: TestContainer) {
    testContainer.test.notes = "y"
}
```

You don't know inside this function how `TestContainer` was configured with class or a struct. I guess swift team considered that always raise `will/didChange` is less confusing behaiour is such case.